# Fitting text bubble to wrapped text in React with MUI

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am writing a ReactJS/MUI chat app, and I am running into problems with the text bubble sizing. The bubble is a Typography component:

```
<Typography variant="body1" sx={bubbleStyle}>
    {text}
</Typography>
```

The styling is provided in:

```
const bubbleStyle = {
    bgcolor: fromUser ? theme.palette.primary.main : '#f1f1f1',
    color: fromUser ? 'white' : 'black',
    p: 1,
    borderRadius: '8px',
    maxWidth: '65%',
    wordBreak: 'break-word',
    display: 'inline-block',
    my: 0,
    fontFamily: 'Inter, sans-serif',
    fontWeight: '100',
    fontSize: '14px',
};
```

When the text is a single line or less, the bubble is sized to fit the text. However, when the text wraps, the bubble is sized to 65% width instead of only being as large as it needs to be to fit the text. here's an example of a "problem" bubble:

[problem bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seoaF.png)

There is extra space on the right side of the bubble.

Here is the full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box, Typography, useTheme } from '@mui/material';

interface MessageComponentProps {
    text: string;
    fromUser: boolean;
    sendTime: Date;
}

export const MessageComponent: React.FC<MessageComponentProps> = ({ text, fromUser, sendTime }) => {
    const theme = useTheme();

    const bubbleStyle = {
        bgcolor: fromUser ? theme.palette.primary.main : '#f1f1f1',
        color: fromUser ? 'white' : 'black',
        p: 1,
        borderRadius: '8px',
        maxWidth: '65%',
        wordBreak: 'break-word',
        display: 'inline-block',
        my: 0,
        fontFamily: 'Inter, sans-serif',
        fontWeight: '100',
        fontSize: '14px',
    };

    const formattedTime = sendTime.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });

    return (
        <Box
            sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: fromUser ? 'flex-end' : 'flex-start',
                width: '100%',
                '&:hover .timestamp': {
                    display: 'block',
                },
            }}
        >
            {fromUser && (
                // For user messages, show the timestamp to the left of the message
                <Typography variant="caption" sx={{ color: 'lightgrey', alignSelf: 'center', mr: 1, display: 'none' }} className="timestamp">
                    {formattedTime}
                </Typography>
            )}
            <Typography variant="body1" sx={bubbleStyle}>
                {text}
            </Typography>
            {!fromUser && (
                // For counterparty messages, show the timestamp to the right of the message
                <Typography variant="caption" sx={{ color: 'lightgrey', alignSelf: 'center', ml: 1, display: 'none' }} className="timestamp">
                    {formattedTime}
                </Typography>
            )}
        </Box>
    );
};
```

What I've tried:

`width='fit-content'` -- Width was fit to the total length (more than 65%), set to 65% as the max, then wrapped, and the extra space was still there.

Making a hidden `<div>` (and later a hidden `<span>` or hidden `<Typography>`) -- Didn't work in the way that I tried it, and sometimes caused other problems with the widths (i.e. wrapping too early) while still having some extra space.

Using a `ResizeObserver` - didn't do anything.

Using a nested `MessageComponentText` component - didn't do anything, I think the bubble wrapped around the same too-big area as before.

Dynamically measuring the text with JS and resizing to the text width - didn't do anything.

I looked at answers to similar questions in HTML/CSS, but I don't know HTML or CSS all that well, so I couldn't port them to MUI.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the best you can do is `word-break: break-all`. It will break your word as well to fit the content and remove any extra **gaps**. I can't find a way to keep your word while removing extra spaces as well.